# Exported Data to an Excel displays date as Number

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2010, export-to-excel

I have exported a list to an excel having some date columns. The list displays the date in the format 24/02/2016 05:35:25, but when exported the list to an excel the date column is displayed as number i.e. 42424.23293.

I am not sure if i am missing any Excel settings here. Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try changing the column type in excel to Date. Right click the column letter (at the top) -> Cell Type > Date > OK. - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel/excel_setting_cell_type.htm

Comment: Thanks, but that's a manual way of doing it, but i want the date format to be retained while the data is exported to an excel.

Comment: depending on how you export to excel, you can code a 2 lines excel macro  that on sheet_load will do this automatically for your users.

Comment: This should be working without having to write a macro, this works fine in many of my box, not sure why its not showing properly in the machine which i am currently working on.

Comment: That particular box is probably MDY instead of DMY. If that's the case, be thankful that it isn't coming in half as malformed dates and half as text. Export the list properly with a [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018%28v=office.12%29.aspx) set to DMY.

Comment: Exactly how are you exporting the data?  What is the nature of the data you are exporting?  How are you importing it into Excel?

Comment: Looks like when the data is exported to excel, Excel is not able to format the cells having date value, when i right click on the cell and click on Format cells i see General category selected under Number Tab, but on all the other machines where it works i see Custom category(dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm) selected for cells having date value.

Comment: @ManishAgarwal What is the Windows Regional Short Date format on the machine where this does not work?

Comment: Short date format (dd/MM/yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could format the excel as all text. I would think that if you put

```
Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
```

somewhere in your code prior to loading the values into cells then this would do the trick.

Comment: I don't wan't to format the content of my excel file instead i wan't to know the root cause for this strange excel behavior. It works fine on almost all the machines we are working on, facing issues with one particular machine. I have checked the regional settings and everything looks good.